# Mimic parse.com push msging with MQTT?

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform, intentfilter, mqtt

Is it possible to mimic parse.com's push service hitting a broadcast receiver's's intent filter with MQTT?

Parse is incredibly unreliable and unscalable, I can't for see that service be able to handle possibly millions of pushes needed. But their feature to allow a push msgs to trigger an intent is invaluable.

So, As I setup up an MQTT service in android, how can I go about allowing incoming msgs to that service to then hit a broadcast receiver's filter, in turn hitting an intent.

Comment: You just need to ensure there is enough information in your message format such that your MQTT client can then call sendBroadcast() with a suitable intent object.

Comment: nice! @hardillb so it is fairly easy to replace parse push and handle possibly 100s of thousands push msgs a min?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about handling 100,000s of messages on the server side, not the client side, then yes it should all be possible

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code snippets in the page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24033580&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en ... Also download the zip that has more code.. You can actually use the process given there to send push notifications using MQTT.